# store MySQL SELECT result in php variable using Prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to user prepared statements to find a user record and store the users ID in a php variable to use later on. I would like to echo the variable contents. How do I check the result using Prepared statements?

My CODE:

```
 if ((isset($_POST['overrideUsername'])) and (isset($_POST['overridePassword'])) and (isset($_POST['overrideUniqueID']))) {



    $overridePasswordInput = $_POST['overridePassword'];
    $overrideUsernameInput = $_POST['overrideUsername'];
    $roleID = '154';
    $overrideUniqueID = $_POST['overrideUniqueID'];

    //Not sure how to properly compare stored passwords vs password given by user...
    $overridePassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($overridePasswordInput);
    $overrideUsername = mysqli_real_escape_string($overrideUsernameInput);





    //connect  to the database 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        printf('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $conn->select_db($dbname);

    if(! $conn->select_db($dbname) ) {
        echo 'Could not select database. '.'<BR>';
    }


$sql1 = "SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE (users.login = ?) AND (users.password = ?)";

    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt1->bind_param('ss', $overrideUsername, $overridePassword);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->bind_result($userID);     
    $stmt1->get_result();


    if ($stmt1->get_result()) {

        echo $userID;

    } else {

      echo 'User credentials incorrect. Please try again';

    }

 $stmt1->close();


 //Close the Database connection.
 $conn->close();

 }//End If statement
```

Further more, this is the pre-existing code the original programmer used to authenticate users into the program:

```
if(!defined("noStartup")){
$scriptname = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
$phpbmsSession = new phpbmsSession;

//Testing for API login
if(strpos($scriptname,"api_")!==false){
    if(isset($_POST["phpbmsusername"]) && isset($_POST["phpbmspassword"])){
        $phpbmsSession->loadDBSettings();

        include_once("include/db.php");
        $db = new db();
        $phpbmsSession->db = $db;

        include_once("common_functions.php");           
        $phpbmsSession->loadSettings($sqlEncoding);
        $phpbms = new phpbms($db);


        if(!$phpbmsSession->verifyAPILogin($_POST["phpbmsusername"],$_POST["phpbmspassword"],ENCRYPTION_SEED))
            $error = new appError(-700,"","Login credentials incorrect",true,true,true,"json");
    } else
        $error= new appError(-710,"","No login credentials passed",true,true,true,"json");
} else {

    $phpbmsSession->loadDBSettings($sqlEncoding);


    include_once("include/db.php");
    $db = new db();

    $phpbmsSession->db = $db;

    $phpbmsSession->loadSettings($sqlEncoding);

    include_once("common_functions.php");
    $phpbms = new phpbms($db);

    if(!isset($noSession))
        $phpbmsSession->startSession();

      if (!isset($_SESSION["userinfo"]) && $scriptname != "index.php") {

        if(isset($loginNoKick)){
            if(!isset($loginNoDisplayError))
                exit();
        } else{
            goURL(APP_PATH."index.php");
        }
      }

   }

  $db->stopOnError=true;
}//end if
```

And the verifying function:

```
function verifyAPIlogin($user,$pass){
    $thereturn=false;
    $this->db->stopOnError = false;

    $querystatement = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, phone, department, employeenumber, admin, usertype
                    FROM users 
                    WHERE login!=\"Scheduler\" AND login=\"".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."\" 
                    AND password=ENCODE(\"".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."\",\"".mysql_real_escape_string(ENCRYPTION_SEED)."\") 
                    AND revoked=0 AND portalaccess=1";
    $queryresult = $this->db->query($querystatement);
    if(!$queryresult) {
        $error = new appError(-720,"","Error retrieving user record",true,true,true,"json");
        return false;
    }

    if($this->db->numRows($queryresult)){
        //We found a record that matches in the database
        // populate the session and go in
        $_SESSION["userinfo"]=$this->db->fetchArray($queryresult);

        $querystatement="UPDATE users SET modifieddate=modifieddate, lastlogin=Now() WHERE id = ".$_SESSION["userinfo"]["id"];
        $queryresult=@ $this->db->query($querystatement);
        if(!$queryresult) {
            $error = new appError(-730,"","Error Updating User Login Time",true,true,true,"json");
        } else
            $thereturn=true;
    }
    return $thereturn;  
  }

}//end loginSession class
```

NOTE: I have already tested that my $_POST() values are successfully coming through to my script.

EDIT:: added more code to give a better overall picture of what I'm attempting to do. Any shared tuturials on password encryption/authenticating users would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your passwords are not hashed? You don't need the table reference (`users.`) on the columns when only one table is being used.

Comment: 1/2 the code we don't know what it is or what values they contain. I suggest you start looking for errors. And why are you using brackets where you don't have to?

Comment: *"I have already tested that my $_POST() values are"* - Sure, but do the variables for them match what you posted?

Comment: @chris85 I'm still trying to find how the original programmer encrypted passwords. He is using an outdated version of phpBMS I'm not as familiar with as well as the ENCODE() mixed in with mysql_real_escape_string() for the user input. So needless to say, the entire process needs to be updated... However, this is also my first time working with password authentication and I'm trying to use prepared statements to do so, All help would be great.

Comment: @Fred I save the $_POST() values to the variables shown. I will edit the question to show that.

Comment: Too much code. Isolate the problem. Be more specific with the question.

Comment: Just use password_hash and password_verify, easy peasy and built in.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for the suggestion. I just did more research on them and am very pleased to find out they exist lol ( I am very new to encryption). That simplifies this process exponentially!

Comment: Well glad it helped, i remember they were a godsend when I learned about them. Added an Answer in case you want to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, PHP now has a couple built in methods to handle encryption and decryption of passwords that you might find helps solve your problem:

[password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and
[password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)